# Rails Strong Params blocks my Jquery datepicker plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

This is a headscratcher for me, a search on google yields no results so I'll try here.  I'm doing a rails app and using the datepicker plug in, so I can see a calendar view when I select my date on a form_for.  Everything works fine, as long as I'm not using strong_params.  Because I'm using the latest version of rails, I need to use the strong_params.  But when I do, the calendar no longer pops up after selecting the date.  What could be the reason for this, and how can I circumvent this problem?

```
class RemindersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @reminder = Reminder.new
  end

  def create
    @reminder = Reminder.create(:date => params[:date])
    flash[:created] = "You've scheduled a reminder"
    redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}/reminders/#{@reminder.id}"
  end


  def show
    @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
  end

  # private

  # def reminder_params
  #   params.require(:reminder).permit(:title, :content, :phone, :date)
  # end

end
```

Comment: Datepicker is on view size that mean it work or not (popup inthis case) is based on html

Comment: So you should try to debug in web browser first of all to check jquery datepicker is work correctly. After this then you will get error for strong params ;)